# @StreamListener define groupId for kafka- How can I set many consumers for the same topic

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka, consumer

I am using java and springboot and Kafka in my application.

I want to define many consumers for the same topic inside Kafka.
Now, I am defining the group ID inside my application properties file:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.myFirstTopic.destination=my-first-topic
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.myFirstTopic.group=my-first-consumer
```

and on the method I am using the annotation:

```
@StreamListener(MyFirstTopicBinding.MY_FIRST_TOPIC)
    public void firstConsumer(@Payload MessageDto dto) {}

@StreamListener(MyFirstTopicBinding.MY_FIRST_TOPIC)
    public void secondConsumer(@Payload MessageDto dto) {}
```

I want both methods to get the same messages....

How can I do it?

Comment: The consumers should be belong to separate consumer groups to receive same messages.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Brooklyn.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#consumer-groups

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that; you need to give each one a different channel name, then

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.myFirstConsumer.destination=my-first-topic
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.myFirstConsumer.group=my-first-consumer
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.mySecondConsumer.destination=my-first-topic
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.mySecondConsumer.group=my-second-consumer
```

Also, `@StreamListener` is deprecated and will be removed soon; you should convert to the functional model.

```java
@Bean
Consumer<MessageDto> myFirstConsumer() {
    return dto -> {...};
}
@Bean
Consumer<MessageDto> mySecondConsumer() {
    return dto -> {...};
}
```

Then

```
spring.cloud.function.definition=myFirstConsumer;mySecondConsumer
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.myFirstConsumer-in-0.destination=my-first-topic
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.myFirstConsumer-in-0.group=my-first-consumer
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.mySecondConsumer-in-0.destination=my-first-topic
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.mySecondConsumer-in-0.group=my-first-consumer
```

**EDIT**

Here is an example when using a single binding and publishing each message to multiple listeners:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So70447378Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So70447378Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Consumer<Message<MyDto>> input(PublishSubscribeChannel multiplex) {
        return msg -> multiplex.send(msg);
    }

    @Bean
    PublishSubscribeChannel multiplex() {
        return new PublishSubscribeChannel();
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "multiplex")
    void firstConsumer(MyDto dto) {
        System.out.println("1:" + dto);
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "multiplex")
    void secondConsumer(MyDto dto) {
        System.out.println("2:" + dto);
    }

    public static class MyDto {

        private String foo;

        public String getFoo() {
            return this.foo;
        }

        public void setFoo(String foo) {
            this.foo = foo;
        }

    }

}
```

```
spring.cloud.function.definition=input
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input-in-0.destination=my-topic
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input-in-0.group=my-group
```

Comment: But if I have ONE channel and I want to set TWO listeners, it's inpossible?

Comment: To do that, you can define a bean of type `PublishSubscribeChannel` with `MyFirstTopicBinding.MY_FIRST_TOPIC` as the bean name and it will be used instead of the default `DirectChannel`. Then, each listener will receive a copy of the message.

Comment: I am sorry to be rude...
Can ypu please share a code snippet with me so I can understand it better?

Comment: I added an example using the preferred functional model.